# Python How to export data from entry widget to Treeview

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to do is to make a listbox using a `Treeview` widget. The listBox is successfully created BUt i don't understand how to export data from entry widget to listbox and i need to REMOVE button for listbox content. the program is working successfully.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


def update_sum(first_number_tk, second_number_tk, sum_tk) :
# Sets the sum of values of e1 and e2 as val of e3
   try:
    sum_tk.set((float(first_number_tk.get().replace(' ', '')) + float(second_number_tk.get().replace(' ', ''))))
   except :
    pass

   root.after(10, update_sum, first_number_tk, second_number_tk, sum_tk) # reschedule the event
   return

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x600')

e1_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e1's val.
e2_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e2's val.
sum_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to set e3's val.

# Entries
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e1_tk)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1)
e2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e2_tk)
e2.grid(row=1,column=2)
e3 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = sum_tk)
e3.grid(row=1,column=3)

e4=tk.Label(root,text="SL")
e4.grid(row=1,column=0)

e3_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e1's val.
e4_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to get e2's val.
sum2_tk = tk.StringVar(root) # Initializes a text variable of tk to use to set e3's val.


# Entries
e5 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e3_tk)
e5.grid(row=2,column=1)
e6 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = e4_tk)
e6.grid(row=2,column=2)
e7 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = sum2_tk)
e7.grid(row=2,column=3)

e8=tk.Label(root,text="DR")
e8.grid(row=2,column=0)

cols = ('name', 'No1', 'No2', 'total sum')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=cols, show='headings')

for col in cols:
    listBox.heading(col, text=col)
    listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    listBox.place(x=10, y=300)


# Will update the sum every second 10 ms = 0.01 second it takes ms as arg.
root.after(10, update_sum, e1_tk, e2_tk, sum_tk)
root.after(10, update_sum, e3_tk, e4_tk, sum2_tk)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just add two new button and two new function, like:

```
b = tk.Button(root,text='Update Listbox',command=update)
b.grid(row=3)

b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Delete Items', command=delete)
b1.grid(row=4)
```

and then the `update()` could be something like:

```
def update():
    listBox.insert('','end',value=('SOME NAME', float(e1.get()),float(e2.get()),float(e3.get())))
    listBox.insert('', 'end', value=('SOME NAME', float(e5.get()), float(e6.get()), float(e7.get())))
```

and then `delete()` to be something like:

```
def delete():
    selected_item = listBox.selection()[0]  # get selected item
    listBox.delete(selected_item)
```

For the `delete()` to work properly, you have to click on the item you want to delete and then click on delete button

The `value` argument is the only place where you will have to make the necessary changes.

Hope it cleared your doubt, do let me know if any more errors or doubt.

Cheers

Comment: `value` is not a valid argument for `insert`.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. When I see "listBox" I assume it's a `Listbox`. Now I see that the widget isn't a `Listbox`, it's a `Treeview`.

Comment: Item SL is inserted, but The item DR is not going to be imported. and i need to Remove button also..

Comment: this function listBox.insert('', 'end', value=('SOME NAME', float(e5.get()), float(e6.get()), float(e7.get())))  not working.

Comment: the error is   listBox.insert('','end',value=('SL', float(e1.get()),float(e2.get()),float(e3.get())))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: @SatishBitla Oh yes it is because the second row entry boxes are empty

Comment: it's working, but i need single button to import all rows information

Comment: @SatishBitla Then you shouldnt leave any boxes empty, make sure till fill all the 4 boxes and then click on the button

Comment: all boxes are filled but inserted only single row..

Comment: @SatishBitla but if you dont fill second row, then how will the treeview fill the second row right? thats why i gave two buttons.

Comment: i filled all rows and i clicked one button but inserted only first row, second row is not inserted

Comment: @SatishBitla Check your code again and verify it with my code, ive run this code and for me it works